# RegularExpressionValidator Error Message not visible

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-validators

I have the following `RegularExpressionValidator` to allow only 4 digits number.

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator4" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtPinCode" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Please make sure to select a PIN with four numeric digits" ValidationExpression="^\d{4,4}$" CssClass="caption">4 Digits Pincode</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

It does Validate but doesn't show the error message:

> Please make sure to select a PIN with four numeric digits

Instead Keeps showing  the text `4 Digits Pincode`. I want this text to get replaced by the Error message. Whats wrong?

Comment: Remove `4 Digits Pincode` Text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "4 Digits Pincode" text goes into the Text property. This is [defined](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.regularexpressionvalidator.aspx) as

> the text displayed in the validation control when validation fails

The ErrorMessage property on the other hand is

> the text for the error message displayed in a ValidationSummary control when validation fails

So they are both treated as **error** message, it's not "one or the other".

You maybe could use that "4 digit" text as placeholder on the input. Or just display it always, next to the validator.

Answer (score 0):

Add `Display="None"` So that the error message will not get displayed until you validate.

```
  <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator4" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtPinCode" Display="None" ErrorMessage="Please make sure to select a PIN with four numeric digits" ValidationExpression="^\d{4,4}$" CssClass="caption"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Comment: But I want to show `4 Digits Pincode` text too before it validates